# Bridgetalk - adobe scripting saving with variables, proper quoting, replace string with variable in string script

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-illustrator, photoshop-script

I'm having an issue with saving a file and I can't tell why it's not working. This is original code. I believe I'm commenting out the variables incorrectly or adobe syntax is incorrect. Does anyone have experience with this? (part that is broken: `,app.activeDocument.saveAs(File('"+psdpath+"'/' + doc.name.replace('PLACEHOLDER', '"+parentdirectory+"'))";`). Quote variations are important otherwise it doesn't properly send to illustrator.

Full script:

```
#target photoshop
//run action in photoshop
app.doAction ("action name", "action set name");
//get path of the open document
var psdpath = activeDocument.path.fsName;
//get directory name of psd, to use in filename later
var parentdirectory = activeDocument.path.name;

//start bridgetalk
var bt = new BridgeTalk;
//targets version 25. v26 crashes if window isnt active at run
        bt.target = "illustrator-25";
//run action in illustrator (which opens an eps w/linked file and performs certain tasks) and then save the document
        var script = "app.doScript('action name', 'action set name'),app.activeDocument.saveAs(File('"+psdpath+"'/' + doc.name.replace('PLACEHOLDER', '"+parentdirectory+"'))";
//the entire action must be within double quotes        
//     var script = alert("test", "this sends alert to photoshop");
//     var script = "alert('test', 'this sends alert to illustrator'),alert('"+psdpath+"', '"+psdpath+"')"; //psdpath is properly sent to illustrator
        bt.body = script;
        bt.send();
```

**UPDATE 03/03/2022**
Partially working (string replace does not work):

```
#target photoshop
var psdpath = activeDocument.path.fsName;
var parentdirectory = activeDocument.path.name;
app.doAction ("Photoshop Action Name", "Photoshop action Set");
var strScript = """
app.doScript("Illustrator Action Name", "Illustrator Action Set"); 
var doc = app.activeDocument;  
if (documents.length > 0){    
    var saveOpts = new EPSSaveOptions(); 
    saveOpts.embedLinkedFiles = embedImage = false;
    saveOpts.embedAllFonts = embedFont = true;
    saveOpts.includeDocumentThumbnails = false;
    saveOpts.saveMultipleArtboards = false;
        fullDocName = doc.fullName;
        for (i=0; i<doc.layers.length; i++){
            if (i-1<0) doc.layers[i].visible = true;
            else {
                doc.layers[i-1].visible = false;
                doc.layers[i].visible = true;
            }
            if (doc.layers[i].locked == false) {    
                docName = doc.layers[i].name+".eps";    
                var saveName = new File ( psdpathh + "/" + parentdirectoryy + ".eps");
                doc.saveAs( saveName, saveOpts );
            }
        }
    }
""";
var editedScript = strScript.replace("psdpathh", psdpath);
var editedScript2 = editedScript.replace("parentdirectoryy", parentdirectory);
BridgeTalk.bringToFront("illustrator"); 
var bt = new BridgeTalk;
        bt.target = "illustrator-25";
        bt.body = editedScript2;
        bt.send();
```

Comment: Did you try the suggested solution?

Comment: someone said to use stringscript which works. see updated question for new code (see UPDATE 03/03/2022). string replace does not work in that code. I'm not sure if it has to do with hex encoding between applications. if youre familiar with this let me know

Comment: Try to change `editedScript.replace("parentdirectoryy", parentdirectory);` to `editedScript.replace("parentdirectoryy", '"' + parentdirectory + '"');`

Comment: I had to use %1 and %2 for some reason

Comment: You can use any letters. Say you can replace "%1" with "xyz" and get the same result. All the point in the quotes: `"/" + parentdirectoryy + ".eps"` gets you something like: `"/" + folder_name + ".eps"` (after replacing) which will mean: `"/undefined.eps"`. Meanwhile `"/" + "'" parentdirectoryy + "'" + ".eps"` should get you: `"/" + 'folder_name' + ".eps"`, which will mean: `"/folder_name.eps"`

Comment: you're right, regarding %1 being arbitrary and xyz would work as well. Quoting within the string script is not necessary though. i was quoting within the string script which is what broke it, eg: var saveName = new File ( psdpathh + "/" + parentdirectoryy + ".eps"); https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator-discussions/bridgetalk-adobe-scripting-saving-with-variables-proper-quoting/m-p/12778229#M311597

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#target photoshop
app.doAction ("ps action name", "ps action set"); //replace w your action details
var psdpath = activeDocument.path.fsName;
var parentdirectory = activeDocument.path.name;
var strScript = """
app.doScript("illustrator action name", "illustrator action set"); //replace w your action details
var doc = app.activeDocument;
if (documents.length > 0){
    // Create the illusrtratorSaveOptions object to set the AI options
    var saveOpts = new EPSSaveOptions();
    // Setting IllustratorSaveOptions properties. 
    saveOpts.embedLinkedFiles = embedImage = true;
    saveOpts.embedAllFonts = embedFont = true;
    saveOpts.includeDocumentThumbnails = true;
    saveOpts.saveMultipleArtboards = false;
        fullDocName = doc.fullName;
        for (i=0; i<doc.layers.length; i++){
            if (i-1<0) doc.layers[i].visible = true;
            else {
                doc.layers[i-1].visible = false;
                doc.layers[i].visible = true;
            }
            if (doc.layers[i].locked == false) {    
                docName = doc.layers[i].name+".eps";    
                var saveName = new File ( "%1/%2 -- suffix.eps"); //replace " -- suffix" to whatever, keep .eps 
                doc.saveAs( saveName, saveOpts );
            }
        }
    }
""";
var editedScript = strScript.replace("%1", psdpath).replace("%2", parentdirectory);
BridgeTalk.bringToFront("illustrator-25"); // switch view to illustrator to prevent crashing 
var bt = new BridgeTalk;
//declare your illustrator version
bt.target = "illustrator-25";         
bt.body = editedScript;
bt.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

As a guess.

Perhaps here `...'action set name'),app.activeDocument...` should be `;` instead of `,`:

```
var script = "app.doScript('action name', 'action set name'); app.activeDocument.saveAs(File('"+psdpath+"'/' + doc.name.replace('PLACEHOLDER', '"+parentdirectory+"'))";
```